# AWS Glue job run failed - no log4j-web module available

Tags: pyspark, log4j, etl, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I wrote the script below to run a Glue job:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

source_data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "source_db", table_name = "source_table")
source_data.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("data")
query = "SELECT id, date_created FROM data"

data_df = spark.sql(query)
data_dynamicframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(data_df.repartition(1), glueContext, "data_dynamicframe")
target_data = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = data_dynamicframe, database = "target", table_name = "target_table", transformation_ctx = "target_data")
job.commit()
```

And I got this message in the Log

```
Thread-4 INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
```

Has anyone incurred in the same situation? Is there something wrong with the script?
Thanks!